# Auto increment hash value retrieval

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, hash

I have a perl script that telnets to some network equipment, runs a command to gather some card information and returns each line into an array which i then map into a hash. What i am looking to do is perform a regex to grab the card numbers at the beginning of each string value in the hash and push them into an array. But, only half of them...Because each card in the equipment is doubled in the ouput because of the way the vendor returns the information after the command.

The following is @output, the output seen after running the command.

```
1/1  1187100L1  , Combo A2+ AE.
1/4  1187100L2  , Combo A2+ K.
1/5  1187100L1  , Combo A2+ V
1/16 1187100L2  , Combo A2+ K
1/1  1187100L1  , Combo A2+ No Alarms
1/4  1187100L2  , Combo A2+ No Alarms
1/5  1187100L1  , Combo A2+ No Alarms
1/16 1187100L2  , Combo A2+ No Alarms
```

There is a portion that divides the scalar value of the @output array by half. What i want to do is perform a $hash{} retrieval and auto increment that by the number of the scalar /2.

I only want to retrieve the first 4 card numbers, 1/1, 1/4, 1/5 and 1/16.

Any suggestions?

Here the part of my code i need help with:

```
if (@output) {
    @ccl = grep ( /Combo/, @output );
    my %hash = map { ++$shn => $_ } @ccl;
    my $an = scalar(@ccl) / 2;
    if ( $hash{0} =~ /^(\d+\/\d+)/ ) {
        push( @numbers, $1 );
        print "@numbers\n";
    }
}
```

The above works fine, but only for the first value in the hash. I want to run this for only half of the values in the hash.

Comment: WHat do you mean by "auto increment"? The only use of that term I know is in databases, where an ID column is automatically assigned with incrementing values as you insert rows. How is it different from simply incrementing the value in the hash?

Comment: In your code, you never use the variable `$an`. Isn't that what you said you wanted to use in the auto increment?

Comment: Exactly, its the variable $an that i want to auto increment the hash value by, which happens to be the number 4 in this case. But i don't know how to apply it between the {} in the $hash{}.What i mean by auto increment is to be able to write the following lines all in one line:
    $hash{0}
    $hash{1}
    $hash{3}
    $hash{4}
Automatically based on the number in $an. If i do $hash{$an} it just means $hash{4}. I want it to perform that command the nubmer of times in $an.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. The hash values are strings, not numbers, so it makes no sense to increment them.

Comment: Not the values themselves, the number of values.

Comment: If you mean the hash keys, say so.

Comment: Why 0, 1, 3, 4, not 0, 1, 2, 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will run your code for the first half of the values in the hash.

```
foreach my $i (0 .. $an-1) {
    if ( $hash{$i} =~ /^(\d+\/\d+)/ ) {
        push( @numbers, $1 );
    }
}
print "@numbers\n";
```

BTW, it seems strange to create a hash by mapping incrementing numbers to the values. That's essentially an array, so why not just use the array?

Comment: I put it into a hash so i could use a reg ex against the scalar values because grepping through an array doesn't return only the pattern i searched for, but the whole line. Now that you mention it, i could likely do it with just an array as in '$array[0]' or something.

I ran the above and it runs the loop but pushes the matched pattern to the end of the array 4 times like this
    '1/1
     1/1 1/4
     1/1 1/4 1/5 
     1/1 1/4 1/5 1/16'

Comment: i rather want just each set of numbers returned once because after this i will be running another command based on those numbers to get individual stats on each card and storing in a database then. It works fine the way it is, but it doubles the data returned in the end.

Comment: You're printing the array each time through the loop. So you're seeing it as it grows. Maybe you should move the `print` statement outside the loop.

Comment: If you have a totally different way for me to write the whole thing, im all for it. Feel free to chop it up and serve it back.

Comment: You're just getting confused by a debugging statement. The result is exactly what you want if I understand you.

Comment: Oh that worked! moved the print statement outside the loop. Wow i did't even realize that. Thanks!

Comment: @erik907: Please consider `@Barmar`'s note *"it seems strange to create a hash by mapping incrementing numbers to the values"*. If you want to store an ordered list of values then you should use an *array*. It is also a questionable strategy to count the number of data lines and use only the first half of them. If you want to ignore data for a card if it appears a second time then you should do just that.

Comment: Yeah, I wonder why you're not just using the first field as the key of a hash. When you're inserting a row into the hash, check whether there's already an entry with that key and skip it.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have written I think this is what you want. It pulls the card number from each line and uses the `%seen` hash to push it onto `@numbers` if it is the first time it has appeared.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @output = <DATA>;

my @numbers;
my %seen;
for (@output) {
   next unless /Combo/i;
   my ($card) = /(\S+)/;
   push @numbers, $card unless $seen{$card}++;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@numbers;

__DATA__
1/1  1187100L1  , Combo A2+ AE.
1/4  1187100L2  , Combo A2+ K.
1/5  1187100L1  , Combo A2+ V
1/16 1187100L2  , Combo A2+ K
1/1  1187100L1  , Combo A2+ No Alarms
1/4  1187100L2  , Combo A2+ No Alarms
1/5  1187100L1  , Combo A2+ No Alarms
1/16 1187100L2  , Combo A2+ No Alarms
```

**output**

```
["1/1", "1/4", "1/5", "1/16"]
```